# Autodesk Forge Viewer 7.24.0 is not loading the model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We have web applications with Autodesk Forge Viewer. Suddenly they start to not load the 3D model, their menu bars and HTML started to shake. **Nothing has changed from our side**. I have thought, the link for the viewer could be problem

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js
```

That's why, I have changed it to lower versions like : 7.10 or 7.23 then the model loads to viewer and there is no shaking issue.

What could be the problem, is there an update on viewer side and should we make changes according to it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Autodesk.AEC.Minimap3DExtension
```

is causing the problem. When I remove it from extensions, the viewer works with newest version or for now 7.24.0. ***Autodesk.AEC.Minimap3DExtension*** works with previous versions of viewer-7 still. Probably there is a change.

Comment: Thanks for the finding and sorry for the issue, I am also checking with our Viewer engineering team, and if there is any other issue related to Viewer 7.24.0, please feel free to let us know.

Comment: Please try to use viewer v7.24.1. The fix of LMV-5592 has been released now.